# Multiple tabhosts or buttons

Tags: android

I'm currently developing app for one shop and as the design came together I stumbled upon a problem. There is one main `activity` which has five `tabs` on top and also in one of those top `tabs` there are two `tabs` on the bottom to switch between activities in that main(top) tab. As I started to develop `UI` I put another `tab host` at the bottom (bad idea, because it somehow corrupts design of `top tabs`(top tab background is streched)).

[image]

So the question is What would be the best way to make 3 `activities` fit and work in one `tab`? Should I use `buttons` or another `tabhost` or some other `widget`?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or mockup?

Comment: @mervinj screenshot is [here](http://hvz.eu5.org/haha.png) this is with out tabs at the bottom(they are linear layouts(for now))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best for this type of app would be a fly-out menu instead of the first-level tabs on the top:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

Google+, and Facebook are two examples of apps that use this pattern.

Inside this menu you could either use something hierarchical or you could still use a tab for the second level - but please use those tabs in conjunction with an ActionBar.

Please read Cyril Mottiers post about how to point out that this menu exists to your users:
http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658

There are even libraries out there to help you with this kind of menu. Juhani Lehtimaeki has links to them in his post (the first one above) as well.